# Deleting a row from recycler view and sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

This is my adapter class:

```
public class adapter_cgpa extends RecyclerView.Adapter<adapter_cgpa.Viewholder> {

    ArrayList<POJO> cgpaArrayList;


    public adapter_cgpa(ArrayList<POJO> cgpaArrayList) {
        this.cgpaArrayList = cgpaArrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public adapter_cgpa.Viewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View listitem = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_cgpa, parent, false);
        return new Viewholder(listitem);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull adapter_cgpa.Viewholder holder, int position) {

        POJO cgpa= cgpaArrayList.get(position);
        holder.cname.setText(cgpa.getCname());
        holder.no_of_sems.setText(cgpa.getNo_of_sems());
        holder.cgpa.setText(cgpa.getCgpa());
        holder.percentage.setText(cgpa.getPercentage());
        holder.schemec.setText(cgpa.getSchemec());


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return cgpaArrayList.size();
    }

    public class Viewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView cname, no_of_sems, cgpa, percentage,schemec;
        ImageButton btndelete2;


        public Viewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            cname=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            no_of_sems=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.no_of_sem);
            cgpa=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView49);
            percentage=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView55);
            schemec=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.scheme2);
            btndelete2=(ImageButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.btndelete2);

            btndelete2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    final String snc = cname.getText().toString();
                    final String semrc = no_of_sems.getText().toString();
                    final String schc = schemec.getText().toString();

                    dbmanager db= new dbmanager(v.getContext());
                    db.delete2(snc,semrc,schc);
                }
            });

        }



    }

}
```

And this is my dbmanager class:

```
public class dbmanager extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    String sgpa_table="create table Sgpa (sname text, semester text, sgpa  text,percent text, schemes text, primary key(sname,semester,schemes))";
    String cgpa_table="create table Cgpa (cname text, no_of_sems int, cgpa text, percentage text, schemec text, primary key(cname,no_of_sems,schemec))";

    public dbmanager(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, "Student", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(sgpa_table);
        db.execSQL(cgpa_table);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }



    public Cursor fetch_data1() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "Select*FROM Sgpa" ;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);

        return cursor;
    }

    public Cursor fetch_data2() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "Select*FROM Cgpa" ;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
//        if (cursor != null) {
//            cursor.moveToFirst();
//        }
        return cursor;

    }


    public boolean delete2(String snc, String semrc, String schc){
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        int result = db.delete("Cgpa", "cname= ? and no_of_sems = ? and schemec = ?", new String[] {snc, semrc, schc});
        return result > 0;
    }

}
```

This is not working. I think that instead of passing the value in textview, I need to pass the item position , that is, row id and column id but I don't know how to do that.                                            Can someone help me out with that?

Comment: It will be fine if you include, what error you are getting or any exception stacktrace to better solve your issue

Comment: There is no error. The delete function is not working. I can see while debugging that snc, semrc and schc (the arguments) are storing blank values. And nothing is getting deleted. It is probably because the recycler view has repeated card views with same textview and image button.

Comment: Delete function is not working or list is not updating after delete. Probably UI is not refreshed after delete. Try calling notifyChanged in adapter to check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to add `notifyDataSetChanged();` after deleting by `cgpaArrayList.remove(position);`

**Edit**

```
  public class adapter_cgpa extends RecyclerView.Adapter<adapter_cgpa.Viewholder> {

        ArrayList<POJO> cgpaArrayList;


        public adapter_cgpa(ArrayList<POJO> cgpaArrayList) {
            this.cgpaArrayList = cgpaArrayList;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public adapter_cgpa.Viewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View listitem = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_cgpa, parent, false);
            return new Viewholder(listitem);

        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull adapter_cgpa.Viewholder holder, final int position) {

            POJO cgpa = cgpaArrayList.get(position);
            holder.cname.setText(cgpa.getCname());
            holder.no_of_sems.setText(cgpa.getNo_of_sems());
            holder.cgpa.setText(cgpa.getCgpa());
            holder.percentage.setText(cgpa.getPercentage());
            holder.schemec.setText(cgpa.getSchemec());
            btndelete2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    delete (position);

                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return cgpaArrayList.size();
        }

        public class Viewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            TextView cname, no_of_sems, cgpa, percentage, schemec;
            ImageButton btndelete2;


            public Viewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                cname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
                no_of_sems = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.no_of_sem);
                cgpa = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView49);
                percentage = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView55);
                schemec = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.scheme2);
                btndelete2 = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btndelete2);


            }


        }
        public void delete(final int position) {
            cgpaArrayList.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            final String snc = cname.getText().toString();
            final String semrc = no_of_sems.getText().toString();
            final String schc = schemec.getText().toString();

            dbmanager db = new dbmanager(v.getContext());
            db.delete2(snc, semrc, schc);
        }

    }
}
```

I hope it will help you .

Comment: how to declare position in that?

Comment: It seems that you have not placed the code inside proper methods.